ModuleNotFoundError from a folder with __init__.py
Sorry if this question has been asked before, but looking at previous answers doesn't really help my case. I pulled some code from git that works for my friend, however when the code doesn't work on my computer. When I try to run a unit test that he wrote, it failed too.
The project looks like analogous this:
Project/
├─ App/
   ├─ __init__.py
   ├─ extensions.py
├─ Tests/
   ├─ unit_test.py

In unit_test.py, I have the following code:
from app import db

where I initialize in /app/__init__.py:
from .extensions import db

When I try to run unit_test.py, I get the following error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

I've tried moving unit_test.py to from the /tests/ folder to the /projects/ folder but that doesn't seem to do anything either. Any reason for this behavior?

I assume that's supposed to be "app" in your tree, and not "App".  How would you expect Python to find "app"?  It's not in the path.  If you chdir to the "project" directory and did python tests/unit_test.py it would work.  Otherwise, you'll need to add that directory to sys.path.

maybe your friend installed code and Python know where to search module app. But now you may need to append folder /full/path/to/project/ to list sys.path before from app import db

you may also add folder to environment variable PYTHONPATH  - doc: 6.1.2. The Module Search Path

moving unit_test.py to projects/ may not work if it needs some other modules from tests/ - so you may get similar error but for different module/file
